# Linux tr command not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, random, passwords

I have this password generator:

```
pass () {
    # Generates a random password
    local size="${1:-12}"
    local alphabet="$2"
    </dev/urandom tr -dc "$alphabet" | head -c$size ; echo ""
}
```

Which works fine as follows:

```
» pass 20 '[:alnum:]'
DpEf8bMp7zfkvSoudItS
```

But fails as follows:

```
» pass 20 '[:alnum:]@#%+-/~'
JSNweE,.EU+P.l5nqkzd
```

The `tr` command is explicitly saying:

> remove all characters which do not belong to the given set

Thus the characters `,` and `.` are unexpected.

Where do they come from?

Comment: Just use `pwgen`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww We had this before. This question is about shell coding. it's on-topic. You should really read the page behind the link which you are posting again and again.

Comment: @jww Bash tag: _For questions about scripts written for the Bash command shell. - - Questions about interactive use of Bash are more likely to be on-topic on Super User than on Stack Overflow._. This question is definitely about a script, not about interactive use.

Comment: @hek2mgl - I believe the bar is higher than adding "... in a script" to a question. If the problem is reduced to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which it appears so), then it is just a question on how to run commands. There are better sites to ask those types of questions.

Comment: @JamesBrown - It is a question on a command. it is not a question about a script. Perhaps I am reading the question wrong or missing something else...

Comment: @jww From the tr tag: _Use this tag only if your question relates to programming using tr. Questions relating to using or troubleshooting tr command-line options itself are off-topic._

Comment: @jww I think this discussion should happen on meta and while I disagree with your very strict interpretation I'm totally open for debating it there plus I think such a discussion would be also good to have as a future reference.

Comment: @jww knowing that it is a question about a command is part of the solution. I suspected `tr`, but was not 100% sure.

Comment: @hek2mgl good to know about `pwgen`, but prefer avoiding extra installs.

Comment: It is also customary to comment when downvoting. This refers to the downvote of the answer.

Comment: @JamesBrown: I'm sure it was done by jww for the mentioned reasons above claiming his usual off-topic blah blah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also another part of `tr`'s man page that you overlooked:

> CHAR1-CHAR2
>
> all characters from CHAR1 to CHAR2 in ascending order

So the part `+-/` will mean the characters `+`, `,`, `-`, `.` and `/`. (`man ascii` is useful here).

For a hyphen you can escape it:

```
pass 20 '[:alnum:]@#%+\-/~'
```

use `\055` instead:

```
pass 20 '[:alnum:]@#%+\055/~'
```

or put it at the end:

```
pass 20 '[:alnum:]@#%+/~-'
```

Comment: ooops! Good catch!